# How to analysis the time complexity of this code?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, c++14, dynamic-programming, code-analysis

It's my Accepted code for this Codeforces problem: [Education Round 1E](http://www.codeforces.com/contest/598/problem/E)

By experience, I can solve it confidently, yet I always find it is hard for me to analysis the time complexity of this kind of algorithm (usually recursion in DP)

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int t;
int N,M,K;
int dp[32][32][52];

int DP(int n, int m, int k){
    if(k > n*m) return 1<<28;
    if(k == n*m || k <= 0) return 0;
    if(dp[n][m][k] != 1<<28) return dp[n][m][k];

    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<=k; j++)
            dp[n][m][k] = min(dp[n][m][k],  DP(i, m, j) + DP(n-i, m, k-j) + m*m);

    for(int i=1; i<m;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<=k; j++)
            dp[n][m][k] = min(dp[n][m][k], DP(n, i, j) + DP(n, m-i, k-j) + n*n);

    return dp[n][m][k];
}

int main() {
    cin >> t;

    for(int i=0; i<32;i++) for(int j=0; j<32;j++) for(int k=0; k<52;k++) dp[i][j][k] = 1 << 28;
    while(t--){
        cin >> N >> M >> K;

        cout << DP(N,M,K) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the common practice to analysis the complexity of the function like `DP(N,M,K)`? I don't think master theorem can apply here because each sub-problem is not of the same size (but I am not sure about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the **dp** matrix. Consider going bottom-up. If you have to compute the value of **dp[n][m][k]**, then all its sub-problems are already solved. Then, the time required to compute this value will be max(n,m)*k. Overall there will be **n*m*k** such values you have to compute. So, the overall time complexity will be **O(n*m*k*max(n,m)*k)**.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but is this analysis method / mindset general for all DP problems ?

Comment: The time complexity of the dynamic programming solution will be the same whether you go top-down or bottom-up. So yes, you can use this method for computing the time complexity in general for DP solutions.

Answer (score 0):

*(Post another possible thought which may help)*

After discussed with my classmate, he suggested a very simple thought:

**Think the recursion as doing a simple DFS**

Then complexity is **O(|V| + |E|)**

Here **|V| = nmk**,  **|E| = |V|(nk+mk)**

So total complexity is **O(nmk + n^2mk^2 + nm^2k^2) = O(max(n,m)*nmk^2)**

I like this modeling but I am not sure this is a general analysis method for such DP solutions, therefore I accept @VikramBishnoi answer which gives the same complexity at the end.